# using aws-sdk to upload images to s3 using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload images to amazon web server and for that I am using aws-sdk with nodejs.

I am able to upload images to the s3 bucket, but when I click on the URL to access them I get access-denied error.

Here is my configuration

```
     var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

     //aws credentials
     AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
     AWS.config.accessKeyId = "<access_key>";
     AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "<secret_key>";
     AWS.config.region = "ap-southeast-1";
     AWS.config.apiVersions = {
        "s3": "2006-03-01"
     }

    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    var bodystream = fs.createReadStream(req.files.pic.path);

    var params = {
        'Bucket': '<bucket_name>',
        'Key': 'uploads/images/' + req.files.pic.name,
        'Body': bodystream,
        'ContentEncoding': 'base64', 
        'ContentType ': 'image/jpeg'
     };

     //also tried with s3.putObject
     s3.upload(params, function(err, data){
        console.log('after s3 upload====', err, data);
     })
```

Images are uploading successfully but their content-type is application/octet. Also I think that there is some permission issue, because when I add a new permission then I am able to download the image but not able to see it.

Can you tell me what is wrong with this configuration and also I want to know the difference between s3.upload and s3.putObject method.

Answer (score 4):

In order to specify `Content-Type` header you need to define `Metadata` section:

```
var params = {
    'Bucket': '<bucket_name>',
    'Key': 'uploads/images/' + req.files.pic.name,
    'Body': bodystream,
    'ContentEncoding': 'base64', 
    Metadata: {
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'
    }

 };
```

Comment: getting this error if I try to specify content-type this way

 {
       [SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does              not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.]
  message: 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.',
  code: 'SignatureDoesNotMatch',
  time: Fri Oct 30 2015 12:55:30 GMT+0530 (IST),
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 30
 }

Comment: @BhushanGoel I've fixed the code, forgot about the dash in `content-type`

Comment: yeah it worked, now in s3 console I can see this in the metadata:

x-amz-meta-content-type: image/png

Comment: but how can I set the permission, I am still getting access denied error

Comment: @BhushanGoel you can either use `putObject` and specify ACL there or you can use `putBucketAcl` to setACL separately

Comment: when I am passing    'ACL': 'public-read' in params, then I am getting access denied in response.

Comment: Does your user have access to modify this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93773/discussion-between-bhushan-goel-and-vsevolod-goloviznin).